# char_x < (char_y + 1) == char_x <= char_y?

Tags: java, algorithm, char

Hi all I was browsing through some of the Java source code when I came across this (`java.lang.Character`):

```
public static boolean isHighSurrogate(char ch) {
    return ch >= MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE && ch < (MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE + 1);
}

public static boolean isLowSurrogate(char ch) {
    return ch >= MIN_LOW_SURROGATE && ch < (MAX_LOW_SURROGATE + 1);
}
```

I was wondering why did the writer added 1 to the higher limit and doing a lesser-than compare, instead of simply doing a lesser-than-or-equal compare?

I can understand if it helps readability, but in this case it doesn't seem to be that case.

I was wondering what's the difference between the code above and this:

```
public static boolean isHighSurrogate(char ch) {
    return ch >= MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE && ch <= MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE;
}

public static boolean isLowSurrogate(char ch) {
    return ch >= MIN_LOW_SURROGATE && ch <= MAX_LOW_SURROGATE;
}
```

Comment: This is a guess, not an answer: Perhaps it's to be consistent with the idiomatic way of writing for loops, e.g. `for (i = LOWER_BOUND; i < HIGHER_BOUND; i++)`.

Comment: Maybe it was meant to emphasize that ch can also be equal to MAX_[HIGH|LOW]_SURROGATE. "<=" is easier to misread as "<" - and the compiler probably optimizes it to the same bytecode anyway.

Comment: Well, for one thing, `MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE` is a char and `1` is an int... there may be some kind of conversion from char to int going on there that may be necessary.

Comment: Never mind, I misread the code. Deleted my answer that should have been a comment anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps the author is trying to be consistent with [Dijkstra's advice](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD831.html) to make all ranges half-open -- the start point is inclusive and the endpoint is exclusive.

There is no semantic difference here, but a subtle difference in bytecode: `(ch + 1)` is an `int` so the first code snippet does a `char` to `char` comparison followed by an `int` to `int` comparison while the second does two `char` to `char` comparisons.  This does not lead to a semantic difference -- the implicit casts are to wider types and so there is no risk of overflow in either code snippet.

Optimizing out the addition and converting the `int` to `int` comparison back into a 2 byte unsigned `int` comparison is well within the scope of the kinds of optimizations done by the JIT so I don't see any particular performance reason to prefer one over the other.

I tend to write this kind of thing as

```
MIN_LOW_SURROGATE <= ch && ch <= MAX_LOW_SURROGATE
```

that way the `ch` in the middle makes it obvious to a reader that the `ch` is being tested within the range of the outer values.

Comment: I'd thought it would have made more sense if he used the same comparison for both sides: `ch >= (MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE + 0) && ch < (MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE + 1)`

Comment: @Pacerier, there's many subtly different ways to say the same thing.  I'd pick whichever one makes underflow/overflow and off-by-1 errors stand out to you and stick with it.

Answer (score 2):

Wild guess

> Surrogate character, any of a range of Unicode codepoints which are
>   used in pairs in UTF-16 to represent characters beyond the Basic
>   Multilingual Plane.

In my point of view he wanted to ignore 8 bit stuff, meaning if the max was 0xFF. the 0xFF+1 would overflow and go back to 0x00. Making the comparison always false.

So if the code was compiled with chars of 8 bits. It would always return false (outside of the UTF-16 range) while if it compiles a char in >8 bits the 0xFF+1 would be 0x100 and still work.

Hope this makes some sence for you.

Comment: `char` is always an unsigned 16-bit integer in java.  The max is 0xDBFF and the min is 0xD800.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say there is no really difference between the two ways of coding it, its just a matter of taste what you would prefer, since you haven't really any advantages of one of the two different implementations.

> I was wondering why did the writer added 1 to the higher limit and doing a lesser-than compare, instead of simply doing a lesser-than-or-equal compare?

I mean, why would you prefer the second choice? Do I miss something here?

Comment: I mean isn't the second choice more readable (makes more logical sense) to you too?

Comment: Nope, actually not since I would expect a difference of at least 1 between MAX and MIN and the + 1 brings this out for me, but thats just my pov.

Answer (score -1):

Because the author was a C++ or an assembler guy.

It's faster to make a >= than > and it's faster to do <= than <. Actually, when you write a < b the compiler makes a<=b+1, so it makes an addition and a compare, because the only available assembly instruction does <=. If you write that sum in the code by hand, a C++ compiler will change MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE + 1 with the actual value  of the result at compile time. So you gain an instruction, and a cycle.

But all this strange reasoning is applying only for compiled code, like C++ or C. Or ASM.

**EDIT**

Although there are instructions for each of the equality operators above (I was wrong), they all boil down to subtractions and (if needed) additions in microcode. Then the processor checks the sign bit of the result. So the above code formulation will still be faster.

To make sure there are no overflows when adding 1, the microprocessor first subtracts, then adds one.

Comment: By that logic, if `b` is MAX_VALUE, then wouldn't that mean `a < b` gives overflow (which doesn't) ?

Comment: You must make sure it doesn't happen. It's the programmer's job.

Comment: On x86, at least, there are instructions for `<=` and `<`.  Same for Java bytecode.  Neither should be faster than the other.  Consequently, I doubt the compiler converts one into the other.

Comment: So it's possible that I am wrong... On the other hand, it's possible that the asm < is converted to <= r+1 by microcode.

Comment: On what mythical CPU is this? Not x86 at least.

Comment: @OliCharleswort, pacerier & harold. Thanks for critics, you helped me recheck and find the correct answer.

Comment: You edit is still wrong. On x86, comparisons are made by a subtraction followed by a branch instruction. The branch instruction checks for a combination of the zero, carry, overflow, and sign flags, depending on which comparison operand you used. Where do you get your information?